# how to break data in column one table that is used to join other tables to get other data

Tags: mysql, sql

how to break data in column one table that is used to join other tables to get other data. the point is 
change the table data from the results of the data fraction column table 2 whose code is the same as table 1

Example

**tabel 1**

```
no       description           code 
1          one                  A
1          two                  B
2          three                C
```

**tabel 2**

```
no         code              codeall
1          ABB                null
1          BBC                null
2          ABC                null
```

I want to be like this

**tabel 2**

```
no            code                  codeall
1               ABB                one, two, two
1               BBC                two, two,three
2               ABC                one,two,three
```

How I modify this query

```
UPDATE tabel1 tb1 JOIN tabel2 tb2 ON tb1.no = tb2.no 
SET tb2.codeall = ... where tb2.no = 1
```

Comment: that is a very poor database schema. do not store data in comma separated fields. store them separately and aggregate them on select only if you want to get a susteinable database schema

Comment: this database from another people. and now i should to make it like that

Comment: @BenyBondBanjarnahor since MySQL 5.7 it is allowed to use JSON data type. It will be more correct to use JSON for `code` column in `table2`. And better rename this column to plural, as it can contain multiple values

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) something like this

```
   UPDATE     
   tabel2 tb2,
    (select tabel1.no, GROUP_CONCAT(tabel1.code) as 'data' from tabel1 group by tabel1.no) as data
SET 
    tb2.codeall = data.data
WHERE
    tb2.no = 1 and data.no = tb2.no
```

Comment: Invalid use of group function.. when i try

Comment: tabel1.id where is from ?

Comment: It should no mb. Corrected.

Comment: Btw, you may need to some correction to sql because I don’t have tables so I can’t run sql

Comment: An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 45)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 45)
A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "select" at position 46)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 153)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 155)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "data" at position 158)
A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "SET" at position 164)

Comment: You need modify sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate *before* doing the `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tabel2 tb2 JOIN
       (SELECT tb1.no, GROUP_CONCAT(description) as codeall
        FROM tabel1 tb1
        GROUP BY tb1.no
       ) tb1
       ON tb1.no = tb2.no 
    SET tb2.codeall = tb1.codeall
    WHERE tb2.no = 1;
```

For performance, you should filter before the aggregation:

```
UPDATE tabel2 tb2 JOIN
       (SELECT tb1.no, GROUP_CONCAT(description) as codeall
        FROM tabel1 tb1
        WHERE tb1.no = 1
        GROUP BY tb1.no
       ) tb1
       ON tb1.no = tb2.no 
    SET tb2.codeall = tb1.codeall
    WHERE tb2.no = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabel 1          
 no     description           code 
 1          39                  4
 1          64                  S
 1          70                  Z

tabel 2          
no        code           codeall
1          4SZ            null

become
tabel 2          
no            code                  codeall
1              4SZ             68,69,70,48,67,66,65 it should (39,64,70)
```

i was try the query